# If $f$ is not uniformly continuous function on $(0,1)$ then $f$ can't be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is this proposition correct? If it is correct can anyone prove it? Because I need it to prove that if $f$ is a continuous function (not uniformly continuous) on $(0,1)$ then it can't be approximated by polynomials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it’s correct. If $f$ had a continuous extension $g$ to $[0,1]$, $g$, being continuous on a compact set, would be uniformly continuous, and its restriction $f=g\upharpoonright(0,1)$ would also be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it.

Comment: @Saikat: You’re very welcome.